# Append tuple elements to a tuple of tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples

If I have a tuple, e.g. `x = (1, 2, 3)` and I want to append each of its elements to the front of each tuple of a tuple of tuples, e.g. `y = (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'))` so that the final result is `z = ((1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'c', 'd'), (3, 'e', 'f'))`, what is the easiest way?

My first thought was `zip(x,y)`, but that produces `((1, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('c', 'd')), (3, ('e', 'f')))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip` and flatten the result:

```
>>> x = (1, 2, 3)
>>> y = (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'))
>>> tuple((a, b, c) for a, (b, c) in zip(x,y))
((1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'c', 'd'), (3, 'e', 'f'))
```

Or, if you are using Python 3.5, do it in style:

```
>>> tuple((head, *tail) for head, tail in zip(x,y))
((1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'c', 'd'), (3, 'e', 'f'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tuple((num, ) + other for num, other in zip(x, y))
```

Or

```
from itertools import chain

tuple(tuple(chain([num], other)) for num, other in zip(x, y))
```

Comment: I don't see any benefit to the `chain` version.

Comment: @AlexHall it's just another option for the record.